# How to add 4 side by side containers

Tags: theming

I would like to add 4 columns/containers just above the footer of the homepage. Similar to the triptych blocks that the Bartik theme offers, except I would like to have 4 of them. I am using a Zen sub theme.

How would I go about adding 4 block and having them display one next to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to define them in your .info file...

```
regions[four_first]   = Footer panel (first)
regions[four_second]  = Footer panel (second)
regions[four_third]   = Footer panel (third)
regions[four_fourth]  = Footer panel (fourth)
```

Then add them to your page.tpl...

```
<?php if ($page['four_first'] || $page['four_second'] || $page['four_third'] || $page['four_fourth']): ?>
    <div id="footer-panels-wrapper">
       <?php print render($page['four_first']); ?>
       <?php print render($page['four_second']); ?>
       <?php print render($page['four_third']); ?>
       <?php print render($page['four_fourth']); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

When you have done this they will appear in /structure/blocks

The rest is down to CSS...

Comment: Thank you. I grabbed the css from the Bartik theme. All good now :)

Comment: Sorry :(
I can't find the tick :(((

Comment: No worries, at least you know how it works now. When you find it, give it a go ;-)

Comment: No worries. You should go through any questions you have raised and see if someone answered them. It helps everyone to know if that fixed the issue. Also it provides an incentive for others to ask any questions you have so they can build their reputation. If you dont people will ignore you ;-)

Comment: See you have done it, well done and welcome aboard.